# Loading JSON via an unvalidated URL - is this a vulnerability?

Tags: web-application, json

I have a webpage that is running some javascript that:

1. Reads in a URL from a URL query param
2. Without validating the URL, makes a request to it
3. Validates the response - ensures that the response is a 200 and parses the JSON in a safe way, extracting the data it expects
4. Uses the parsed data for some additional requests. Of course these additional requests fail unless the attacker-controlled server somehow serves valid information, which it should never have access to.

This seems like a vulnerable flow to me, though I haven't found a way to convincingly exploit the lack of URL validation. The specific attack scenario I was playing out is an attacker that set the arbitrary URL to point to a server they control, and sends that link to a legitimate user. Their server would have open CORS permissions and send back whatever data the attacker specifies.

The protections I have:

- The request is made via Javascript on the webpage, so SSRF doesn't apply here.
- The HTTP response from the specified server has to return a 200, otherwise the Javascript throws an error.
- The JSON response is parsed and validated - Attackers can send whatever values they want, but I don't think they can send anything that breaks the Javascript and allows for XSS, for instance.
- The request is a normal Ajax XMLHTTPRequest, which seems to prevent any control over the user's browser window such as open redirects or simply prompting the user to download malware.

If I'm performing proper validation on the JSON, is there a reason I need to validate the URL I'm pulling it from? Does allowing an attacker to specify an arbitrary GET request on a user's behalf through a benign-looking link constitute a security risk?

Comment: “Uses the parsed data for some additional requests” seems relevant. What’s the “valid information” that the attacker can’t provide? Is there some kind of MAC involved?

Comment: _parses the JSON in a safe way_ is the critical part of it. Can you really assure the parser is safe?

Comment: @Ry- The data the javascript expects is a user ID and csrf token. What do you mean by MAC?

Comment: @ThoriumBR the JSON is parsed with Javascript's JSON.parse() method, which by all accounts I've seen is safe to deserialization and other common parsing vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Ry- The auth is done with cookies, so no auth information will be sent to an attacker's server via the xhr request.

Comment: @Buffalo5ix: All of this is about “Uses the parsed data for some additional requests”. How does the JSON response affect those additional requests?

Comment: @Ry- the parsed data is a user ID and csrf token that is placed in the body of another request. Using this vector it is true an attacker could spoof those values, though I don't see the risk there as improper CSRF and user ID values result in a discarded request.